# Using CodeMirror as elFinder editor

Tags: javascript, editor, codemirror, file-manager, elfinder

CodeMirror with elFinder! Wasn't able to find an example anywhere so had to figure it out. It turns out to be really simple in the end, but it took a bit to figure out so I'm posting this because someone out there is bound to need it eventually.

```
$().ready(function() {

    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
        url : 'elfinder-2.0-rc1/php/connector.php',

        commandsOptions: {

            edit : {
                // list of allowed mimetypes to edit
                // if empty - any text files can be edited
                mimes : ['text/plain', 'text/html', 'text/javascript', 'text/css'],

                // you can have a different editor for different mimes
                editors : [{

                    mimes : ['text/plain', 'text/html', 'text/javascript', 'text/css'],

                    load : function(textarea) {

                        this.myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
                            lineNumbers: true,
                            theme: "xq-dark" 
                        })                                        
                    },

                    close : function(textarea, instance) {
                        this.myCodeMirror = null;
                    },


                    save : function(textarea, editor) {                                      
                        textarea.value = this.myCodeMirror.getValue();
                        this.myCodeMirror = null;
                    }

                } ] //editors
            } //edit

        } //commandsoptions

    }).elfinder('instance');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is above!
I should really have asked this as a question and then answered it.  Sorry.

Comment: am using this code its working fine but code mirror theme is not working.I dont understand why